# Iterate through known number of elements in array and get the key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a website and I am using php to print both key and value from an array

```
$array = array(
    "gfo"   => "Fondant",
    "gdo"   => "Domino",
    "ges"   => "Espir",
    "gam"   => "Amara",
    "gsa"   => "Sandwich",
    "gme"   => "Merme",
    "cza"   => "Zarza",
    "cor"   => "Oreo",
    "cal"   => "Almen",
    "cca"   => "eche",
    "cch"   => "Chocolate"
);
```

but I want ONLY first 6 elements be displayed in a menu   like

```
<li>
<a href="product1.php" style="padding:8px 30px;">Product 1</a>
  <ul>                
     <?php foreach($array as $key=>$val):?>
    <li><a href="http://www.site.com.mx/products.php?id=<?=$key?>"><?=$val?></a></li>
     <?php endforeach;?>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And then the other 5 elements in other menu

```
<li>
<a href="product2.php" style="padding:8px 30px;">Product 2</a>
  <ul>                
     <?php foreach($array as $key=>$val):?>
    <li><a href="http://www.site.com.mx/products.php?id=<?=$key?>"><?=$val?></a></li>
     <?php endforeach;?>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I know I can use

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

and

```
for ($i = 6; $i <= sizeof($array); $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

But how to get the key and value in both for loops?

Comment: array_slice() is one way

Comment: I was going to suggest that, however array_slice does not preserve associative array keys.

Comment: @jeffp only if they are numeric (which they are not here), and only if you don't use the flag preserve_keys (5.0.2+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` for that:

```
$i = 1; reset($array);
// get the first 6
while ($i <= 6 && list($key, $val) = each($array)) {
        echo "$key = $val\n";
        ++$i;
}

// get the rest    
while (list($key, $val) = each($array)) {
        echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `array_slice()` but make sure to preserve the keys:

```
$first_six = array_slice($array, 0, 6, true);
$rest = array_slice($array, 6, null, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_chunk` to split the array into two separate chunks and then iterate over each of those:

```
$chunked = array_chunk($array, 6);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with slice()

```
$first_array = slice_array($array,0,6);
$second_array = slice_array($array,6,10);
```

and then do your act,You can also use

```
$first_array = array_chunk($array,6);
$second_array = array_chunk($array,6,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_keys() and array_values() functions

```
$array = array(
    "gfo"   => "Fondant",
    "gdo"   => "Domino",
    "ges"   => "Espir",
    "gam"   => "Amara",
    "gsa"   => "Sandwich",
    "gme"   => "Merme",
    "cza"   => "Zarza",
    "cor"   => "Oreo",
    "cal"   => "Almen",
    "cca"   => "eche",
    "cch"   => "Chocolate"
);
$keys = array_keys($array);
$values = array_values($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    <li><a href="http://www.site.com.mx/products.php?id=<?=$keys[$i]?>"><?=$values[$i]?></a></li>
}
```

and

```
for ($i = 6; $i <= sizeof($array); $i++) {
    <li><a href="http://www.site.com.mx/products.php?id=<?=$keys[$i]?>"><?=$values[$i]?></a></li>
}
```

Put in the necessary open/close php tags